# CTRL+C Batch File Without Closing It

Tags: java, windows, loops, batch-file, client-server

Even though I always use Eclipse for programming in Java, I'm a newbie in using batch's files to execute jar files.

However, I'm creating a client/server project, and now that I'm testing it, I would need to stop the batch executing in order to check the output generated WITHOUT closing the related batch window.

I can't use the `pause` command because they are looping programs (simulating a "never-ending client/server talking")...but if I use CTRL+C and I kill it, the windows will close!

Is there a way to use the CTRL+C command without close the batch?

Comment: you can't invoke `ctrl+z` in simple batch.You can use powershell command or vbscript/jscript

Answer (score 5):

just start your batch with the `cmd /k` option:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my windows version is in italia, so I will try to translate the error when I use your suggested command:

"C:\User\luca-kun\BATCH.BAT" is not an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: My command line is only an example. Feel free to place your own command line there.